# Nginx and pseudo-streaming

Tags: nginx, video-streaming

I use these modules for compiling nginx for streaming videos on my web site by these options:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.8.1 
built by gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015 
TLS SNI support enabled 
configure arguments: --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi 
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy 
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi 
--lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-http_dav_module 
--with-http_flv_module --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions 
-fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --with-http_geoip_module 
--with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_realip_module 
--with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_sub_module 
--with-http_xslt_module --with-ipv6 --with-sha1=/usr/include/openssl --user=www-data --group=www-data 
--without-mail_pop3_module --without-mail_imap_module --without-mail_smtp_module --with-http_stub_status_module 
--with-http_spdy_module --with-md5=/usr/include/openssl --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module 
--with-http_secure_link_module --add-module=naxsi-master/naxsi_src/ --with-http_gunzip_module --with-file-aio 
--with-http_addition_module --with-http_random_index_module --add-module=ngx_cache_purge-2.3/ 
--with-http_degradation_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-pcre --with-google_perftools_module 
--with-debug --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/client --add-module=nginx-rtmp-module-master/ 
--add-module=headers-more-nginx-module-master --add-module=nginx-vod-module-master/ 
--add-module=/home/user/M/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.2-beta/
```

and also i buy jwplayer for serving video on my site.

and this is my configuration on Nginx for pseudo streaming on nginx.conf:

```
location videos/ { 
flv; 
mp4; 
mp4_buffer_size 4M; 
mp4_max_buffer_size 10M; 
limit_rate 260k; 
limit_rate_after 3m; 
#mp4_limit_rate_after 30s;}
```

but when i do this: http://172.16.1.2/videos/a.mp4?start=33

video started from beginning. whats wrong in my configuration? what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should fix:

`location /videos/ { 
flv; 
mp4; 
mp4_buffer_size 4M; 
mp4_max_buffer_size 10M; 
limit_rate 260k; 
limit_rate_after 3m; 
}`

Comment: Pointing out the leading slash before the word "videos" on the first line would've made it easier to work out what your solution was.